# Using huggingface transformers trainer method for hugging face datasets

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface

I am trying to train a transformer(Salesforce codet5-small) using the huggingface trainer method and on a hugging face Dataset (namely, "eth_py150_open"). However, I'm encountering a number of issues.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import torch
import transformers
from datasets import load_dataset_builder
from datasets import load_dataset

corpus=load_dataset("eth_py150_open", split='train')

training_args = transformers.TrainingArguments( #general training arguments
    per_device_train_batch_size = 8,
    warmup_steps = 0,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    learning_rate = 1e-4,
    num_train_epochs = 12,
    output_dir = './runs/run2/output/',
    logging_dir = './runs/run2/logging/',
    logging_steps = 50,
    save_steps= 10000,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)

model = transformers.T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('Salesforce/codet5-small').cuda()

trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model = model,
   args = training_args,
    train_dataset = corpus,
)
```

However, when running trainer.train(), I get the following error:

```
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 74749
  Num Epochs = 12
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 8
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 8
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 112128
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3435b262f1ae> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _prepare_inputs(self, inputs)
   2414         if len(inputs) == 0:
   2415             raise ValueError(
-> 2416                 "The batch received was empty, your model won't be able to train on it. Double-check that your "
   2417                 f"training dataset contains keys expected by the model: {','.join(self._signature_columns)}."
   2418             )

TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I have tried converting corpus to a torch Dataset object, but can't seem to figure out how to do this. I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize the dataset before you can pass it to the model. Below I have added a `preprocess()` function to tokenize. You'll also need a `data_collator` to collate the tokenized sequences. Since T5 is a seq2seq model I am guessing you are trying to generate the license string hence I have replaced `Trainer` with `Seq2SeqTrainer`. (Although I think it would be better if you consider this a sequence classification task). Here's your updated script.

```
import torch
import transformers
from datasets import load_dataset
from tokenizers import AutoTokenizer

corpus=load_dataset("eth_py150_open", split='train')

model = transformers.T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('Salesforce/codet5-small').cuda()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('Salesforce/codet5-small')

def preprocess(examples):
    model_inputs = tokenizer(examples['filepath'], truncation=True)
    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        labels = tokenizer(examples['license'], truncation=True)
    model_inputs['labels'] = labels['input_ids']
    return model_inputs

tokenized_dataset = corpus.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)

training_args = transformers.Seq2SeqTrainingArguments( #general training arguments
    per_device_train_batch_size = 8,
    warmup_steps = 0,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    learning_rate = 1e-4,
    num_train_epochs = 12,
    output_dir = './runs/run2/output/',
    logging_dir = './runs/run2/logging/',
    logging_steps = 50,
    save_steps= 10000,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)

data_collator = transformers.DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, model=model)

trainer = transformers.Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model = model,
    args = training_args,
    train_dataset = tokenized_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator
)
```